# Difference between the spread syntax and manual assigning properties

Tags: javascript

I've a problem with copying objects. 
When I copy the needed properties manually all works fine, but when I try to use the `Object.assign` method or the spread operator I lose some data in further steps in my application. So there's my question:
Is there **any** real difference by manual copying of properties and using the spread operator/Object.assign?

As I mentioned I've tried the spread operator, the `Object.assign` method and manual copying of properties:

```
// works
const bar = {
    data: response.data,
    foo: response.foo
}

//doesn't work
const bar = { ...response}

//doesn't work too
const bar = Object.assign({}, response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use spread syntax or `Object.assign`, *only* the object's **own enumerable** properties are copied.

See MDN. [On spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

> It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

[On `Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

In contrast, when you just plain reference a property, like `response.data`, the property value will be retrieved even if it's not enumerable, or if it's in the prototypal inheritance chain.

```js
const proto = { prop: 'onPrototype' };
const obj = Object.create(proto);
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop2', { value: 'notEnumerable', enumerable: false });

const copiedSpread = { ...obj };
const copiedObjectAssign = Object.assign({}, obj);

console.log(
  copiedSpread, // nothing
  copiedObjectAssign, // nothing
  obj.prop, // works
  obj.prop2 // works
);
```

So, the `data` and `foo` properties must either not be enumerable, or be on an internal prototype of `response` (but not on `response` itself).

To iterate over all properties, enumerable or not, on the object and all of its internal prototypes, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:

```js
const proto = { prop: 'onPrototype' };
const obj = Object.create(proto);
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop2', { value: 'notEnumerable', enumerable: false });


let checkingObj = obj;
while (checkingObj) {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(checkingObj).forEach((propName) => {
    console.log(propName);
  });
  checkingObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(checkingObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and spread syntax copy all the **enumerable own properties** from the source object to the target. If `data` and `foo` are from the [[prototype]] of `response`, it will not be copied over to the target object

If you check the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) of `Object.assign()`

```
for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
    to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like that way

```
const {data, foo} = response
```